# NUnit tests run on build server, but report incorrect count in test results

Tags: nunit, automated-tests, tfsbuild

Using TFS 2012, we have a build configured to run our NUnit tests. All of our test projects have the [NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012 and VS2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/) nuget package installed. With the [corresponding extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) installed, all tests run locally in VS2013 using its test harness (Test Explorer window).

On our TFS build server, however, our tests are run, but the test results in our build output report an incorrect test count. Using just one of our test projects which has 228 unit tests, the build reports that 65 of 65 ran correctly. When viewing the results, the 65 tests that appear are the first 65 tests ordered by the fully qualified class name alphabetically. When we view the build log, however, we see that all 228 unit tests were successfully executed.

What would make the test count incorrect? And any ideas as to how to correct this?

Comment: Try to apply test case [filters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/09/26/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-using-testcasefilter.aspx). Does it make any difference?

Comment: The same issue here with TFS 2013. What's more, when I look at Test Results it shows me more tests (but not all) than what is in the report. In my case it's something like 65 tests ran, in test results I can see 100+ but when I go to build diagnostics I can see all 200+ tests named and run.

Comment: having the same problem here.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem, I've more than 2500 unit test in the solution and build result reports inconsistent unit test count, some times 128 and 150 and so on. Has anyone found the solution?